# How to install the OS with LTS Enablement Stacks (HWE) directly via netboot?

Tags: system-installation, kernel, pxe, hardware-enablement-stack

I need to install Ubuntu 18.04.5 (Bionic) onto a bunch of servers using a [netboot installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apas01.html#howto-getting-images-netboot). These servers have newer hardware and thus need the Kernel provided by [LTS Enablement Stacks (HWE)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

I understand that I can manually install the new kernel provided the HWE Stacks by hand on each server after netbooting the node. But this isn't the devops way, and requires more manual work for me. I'd rather do it automatically from the netboot scripts.

Does Ubuntu provide a repository that allows me to Netboot to an updated HWE kernel? Should I install directly from the [bionic-updates](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates) repository instead of the default bionic repository? I've searched around and cannot find an answer for netbooting.

Comment: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/

Comment: ps:  if you have trouble finding current ISOs, a quick solution I use is via iso.qa.ubuntu.com (http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/415/builds) which will direct you to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543.17/images/netboot/mini.iso    It's the final RC which became 18.04.5 ISO

Comment: @guiverc: When I ask _Should I install directly from the bionic-updates repository instead of the default bionic repository?_, it sounds like your answer is yes.

Comment: I haven't used the netboot ISO in years so I'd be careful trusting me on this subject. My *feeling* is you were correct thus initial comment, then shortly afterwards I added the second *thouight* which is what I'd like do/use (or at least check both are identical, via download or more likely comparison of `sha256sum` to ensure it was correct; the iso.qa site I use a number of times a week and thus have a higher *confidence* level there.  my 2c